# How does auto restart of downloads work?

Tags: http, networking, browser, download

Suppose i am downloading a file of 10 MB, after 4 MB was downloaded network failed, After the network came back it auto restarted the download, How did this happen technically??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are downloading file sequentially you can create a temporary file for meta-information. Then each time you download X bytes, you write the downloaded bytes to a file and you increase the number of downloaded bytes in your meta-information file.

If your connection breaks, next time your file transfer program stars it checks if there is a meta-information file in the downloads directory. If there is one - it checks the number of bytes downloaded and requests the resumption of the download fast-forwarded by the number of bytes already present.

Comment: Thanks for enlightening me :)

Comment: :Can i also say that at an abstraction level error control mechanism at Transport layer are at work here, Such as sliding window which uses acknowledgements while receiving packets and if ack not received it will resend the stream of packets...going deeper even the TCP Header has Sequence Number and Acknowledgement field which assists in keeping track of the packets sent. Please let me know your views.